# How to Disable asp.net button on Grid View row created

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a datatable with 8 columns.Based on a column value, i need to disable the button in each row of the grid view.How to achieve this.Below is what i have tried.

C#

```
dt.Columns.Add("CanLock");
```

ASPX page

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-clr-white">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button disabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CanLock"))?true:false %>' CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-approve %>"  ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderID") %> ' meta:code='<% DataBind(); %>'/>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalRejection" disabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CanLock"))?true:false %>' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-reject' id="btnRejectApp" data-id='<%# Eval("OrderID") %>'>Reject</a>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Unfortunately buttons in every row  are disable when i do this.

Comment: How about setting enabled property like this: `<asp:Button Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CanLock")) %>'  ... >`? `disabled` is a boolean attribute, you shouldn't use it with `Eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute sets the input element in disabled state while the attribute is present, because [`disabled` is a boolean attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled). If you want to disable a server control, you should use [`Enabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled?view=netframework-4.7.2) property instead:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" 
            Enabled='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CanLock")) %>' 
            CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-approve %>" Text="Approve" ... />
```

If the `Enabled` property is set to `false`, then `disabled` attribute will append automatically on the generated `<input type="button" />` element.

**Note:** For your convenience, try replace plain anchor tag inside `ItemTemplate` section with `asp:HyperLink` control which capable for `Eval` usage, also by setting `Enabled` attribute like button above.

Related issue:

[How to disable button based on column value in another GridView column](https://forums.asp.net/t/2053743.aspx?Gridview%20How%20to%20disable%20button%20based%20on%20column%20value%20in%20another%20column)